Pauling's Rule 1: How Did We Relate Cation/Anion Ratio to Coordination Number?
Pauling's rules are used to predict the crystal structure of ionic minerals. The first rule is as so:

Radius Ratio Principle: Cation-anion distances are equal to the sum of their effective ionic radii, and cation coordination numbers are determined by the ratio of cation to anion radii.

I am aware that X-ray diffraction is used to find ionic radii, and that the angles of light calculated from the device are converted to angstroms, the distance between atoms. However, we are then given a convenient chart that offers what C.N. to expect from a certain cation/anion ratio; for example, halite has a ratio of 0.63, and it has an octahedral coordination based on the chart (It does):



Cation/Anion Ratio
Expected Coordination
Coordination Number




<0.15
2-Fold Coordination
2


0.15-0.22
Triangular Coordination
3


0.22-0.41
Tetrahedral Coordination
4


0.41-0.73
Octahedral Coordination
6


0.73-1.0
Cubic Coordination
8



Was this chart derived from experiential analysis of some sort by comparing ratios to example crystals? Are the ratios just communicating the sizes of cations and anions, and thus by size matching ionic radii alone, there is a logic to what can or can not fit, simply put? My instructor said that the biggest control on crystal shape is just the relative size of the atoms, which is predicated on their charge.

Diffraction gives you distances between neighbouring atoms. From there atomic/covalent/vdW radii were made, by splitting them up. And then you can find how they correlate with number of neighbouring atoms.

Sorry for the confusion. So is that why the ranges for CN are variable, because distance is not the best measure for crystal habit? I.e., not a direct correlation?

This chart in the question is not based on experiments. It is purely theoretical, based on geometry of close-packing of spheres. It represents the fact that if cations were smaller than certain limit, coordination numbers would change in order to optimize the nearest neighbor distance, while maintaining equal distance from as many anions as possible. The last statement only holds true experimentally in most cases, not all. Well known exceptions are ferroelectric crystals.
